# What does the Stack Exchange inbox icon represent -- and how could it be improved

Tags: discussion, icons, stack-exchange

Ever since I started using Stack Exchange, I've been slightly annoyed by the inbox icon users see when they're logged in:

[image: Stack Exchange inbox icon and tooltip]

Other sites, such af [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub), use the same metaphor:

[image]

Font packages, such as FontAwesome, also include the icon to represent an inbox:

[image]

Each time I see the icon, I start thinking: "What does this stand for?" I mean, it kind of looks like a purse or a front-view of a train cockpit, but the first thing that comes to my mind is definitely *not* a mailbox.

I know icons (especially monocrome ones) are hard to design, but this shouldn't be too difficult to improve on. Any suggestions for a better alternative?

Comment: I don't appreciate migrating the question to Meta, because it effectively makes it inaccessible to the UI/UX experts I targeted the question to at SE UX. Is this not a proper UX question?

Comment: And marking this as a duplicate of an another question in _Meta_ is just ridiculous. The whole purpose of my question was to get ideas of a better alternative from UX experts. Don't hide the question here when the icon obviously needs improving! To me, this looks like critique to the site's UX is not taken professionally.

Comment: "Any suggestions for a better alternative?" is that really the kind of questions UX favours?

Comment: @random, it should be up to the UX community to decide, not a bunch of people who are active in Meta.

Comment: I can't agree with migration; voting to reopen to reject the migration later.

Comment: Your tone is all up in about how Stack Exchange is doing it, it's no surprise it looked like the question was lost. You could have included other sites like GitHub, or mention other sites that use Font Awesome.

Comment: Voted to reopen on the basis this question has an entirely different discussion point the supposed dupe - "how can we improve it". And so the other question cannot answer this one.

Comment: Flagged to reopen and move back to main site.

Comment: It would be easier if you all downvoted it to past -3 so we can just delete it

Comment: @random - Why do we need to delete it? Why can't we just move it back to where the author originally posted it and is appropriate, based on the author's intent?

Comment: It has to be deleted from this site, when it does, it'll be back on the origin site unlocked, to deal with from there @evi

Comment: **"How to visually represent X" questions are on-topic at the [Graphic Design SE site](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)**. I'd suggest phrasing it like similar questions on [save icons](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/323/) and [edit icons](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6971/)  to avoid ambiguity: e.g. "New generation of 'notifications inbox' icon that isn't an old-fashioned in-tray?"

Comment: The recent edit by Evil Closet Monkey makes the "what does the icon stand for" part of the question (and also me) look pretty daft. I mean, if I already knew that other sites use a "desktop inbox" icon, I would have formulated the question differently. Why not include the edit in your answer ECM? Would make much more sense there.

Comment: Also, [UX.SE migrate "How to visually represent..." questions to the graphic design site](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/759/) because they're not quite on topic at UX.SE (they're "Visual Design", not "UX Design"). While we're talking design, FYI part of the reason 'intray' icons are so problematic is that to understand them, you need to interpret the diagonals as 3D perspective, but 99%+ of flat-design icons have no perspective (it's a feature of the style), so many users are pre-conditioned to not see it that way.

Comment: @MickMnemonic: I can't see why "the icon obviously needs improving". That's a truly subjective statement.

Comment: @Werner, have a look at the proposed duplicate and the discussion there, I think it's obvious.

Comment: Stack Exchange (all sites) are not a discussion forum

Comment: @MickMnemonic - my edit was an attempt to make the question less SE focused, to make it (perhaps) better suited to be moved back to UX.SE which is where you want it. Nowhere in the edit do I say it is obvious what the icon means on other sites, and I use the same language you are using to refer to them on those sites. If you don't like the edit, update it or revert it. I apologize for making the effort.

Answer (score 12):

It represents a classic desk in/out box.

[image]

As to how it could be improved, you point out the issue with answering the question:

> I know icons (especially monocrome ones) are hard to design, but this shouldn't be too difficult to improve on.

They are difficult, and it actually *is difficult* to improve on.

This is because icons are learned experiences. From the NNGroup article [Icon Usability](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/icon-usability/):

> A user’s understanding of an icon is based on previous experience. Due to the absence of a standard usage for most icons, text labels are necessary to communicate the meaning and reduce ambiguity.

For me, I know exactly what it represents and it works just fine for me. Something else that works just fine for you might be ambiguous to me.

Why not an envelope? They are kind of like little mail notices. But not really. Also, snail mail (i.e., envelopes) are becoming less and less used.

How about just a dot? Like an LED status display. Dots are meaningless in themselves though, and certainly wouldn't *add* anything.

How do we make it better? Put a text label next to it.

Beyond that, it will always produce ambiguity since the user must learn what it means before attaching context to it.